# How to access method in separate viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have tried adding an instance method for the @selector but that doesn't seem to do it.

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(displayRandomQuesDefinition)];
```

The method that is in the `@selector` is in a separate view `controller.m`. Maybe there is a way to do this with `[UIView setAnimationDelegate:];` but I still can't figure it out.

This is the code I want to happen when the animation ends:

```
@implementation SecondViewController
- (void)displayRandomQuesDefinition{
    label.text=@"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @selector to call a method in the current object.  From there, call the method in the second method.

```
...    
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myLocalMethod)];
...

- (void)myLocalMethod
{
     [otherViewControllerObject displayRandomQuesDefinition];
}
```

Comment: That works but when I do the +(void) method in the SecondViewController, I can't access the .h labels, and objects. Is there a way to get access to those in it?

Comment: A class method calllooks like [SecondViewController displayRandomQuesDefinition];

Comment: Not sure what you mean about not accessing the .h labels and objects.  You should add the class method signature to the .h

Comment: /Developer-old/12-30/1-4-12/WordGame/1/Word Game/TU11/TU11/LOT/LOT/ViewController.m:47:5:{47:5-47:55}: warning: class method '+displayRandomQuesDefinition' not found (return type defaults to 'id') [3]
THis is the error I get

Comment: I want to use the IBOutlets in the SecondViewController for the displayRandomQuesDefinition. THen use it as a selector for the did endanimation.

Comment: In your original question you have - (void)displayRandomQuesDefinition as an object method (No plus sign).  Perhaps in the .h you have it defined as a class method (With plus sign).

Comment: Yes I did because the warning told me to. Also when I change it back to a plus sign the code doesn't execute.

Comment: Yes I did because the warning told me to, I changed it back though. Also when I change it back to a plus sign the code doesn't execute. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here's my code again: @implementation SecondViewController

-(void)displayRandomQuesDefinition{
    labels.text=@"Hi"; - this is what I want to execute when the animation ends. It doesn't work
}